# Normalization, Primary Key Dependency Candidate Key

Tags: database, dependencies, key, normalization, candidate

In the process of decomposition to normalize a relation. 
If I reach the point where all attributes in a relation depend on the primary key, can I assume that they will all depend entirely on the different candidate keys? 
If that is not a case can you please give me an example of a case where all attributes depend on the primary key, but some of them depend on the part of other candidate keys.

I'm starting learning databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrogate primary IDs make an example really easy:

```
(row_id PK, student_id, course_id, student_name)
```

where `row_id` and `(student_id, course_id)` are candidate keys and `student_id -> student_name`.  Of course the `row_id` trivially determines any other attributes if it's an auto-incremented number.

Comment: Ok, things are getting clear.
Just one point. I don’t see any utility for surrogate keys in case that we already have (student_id) that can be a primary key. 
Are only the cases with surrogate keys out of my statement? 
Thanks

Comment: No, this can happen whenever a table has multiple candidate keys of which at least one is composite.  Consider the final example on Wikipedia's 2NF page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form#2NF_and_candidate_keys.  I could also construct other examples using dates, SSNs, cartesian/polar coordinates as candidate keys, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I now have to check for each candidate key